# The talks are envisaged to take place in the spring

Tags: word-usage

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/envisage?q=envisage):
(1a) It is envisaged that the talks will take place in the spring.

my variants:
(1b) The talks are envisaged to take place in the spring.
(1c) Some people envisage the talks to take place in the spring.

Is (1b) correct?
Is (1c) correct?

I made up (1b) & (1c) by analogy with "expect" which, as I know, is correct here:
(2a) It is expected that the talks will take place in the spring.
(2b) The talks are expected to take place in the spring.
(2c) Some people expect the talks to take place in the spring.

If you say (1b) & (1c) are incorrect, then why are (2b) & (2c) correct?

Answer (score 1):

The variants are correct, but 1c would be much more natural as:

"Some people envisage the talks taking place in the spring."